# Mock vertical scroll in eqnarray/align environment

Tags: beamer, eqnarray

I find that the size of beamer frames is often too small to display verbose calculations. Running a calculation over multiple frames is awkward and one could wish for a vertical scroll on slides. Failing this, it would be good to have a ‘mock scroll’ that would for example display the right hand side of an ‘equation array’ sequentially for two or three iterations, and from then on scroll up from the bottom, dropping the top line each time.

Ideally one would have a function that would take as input the left hand side of the equation and the sequence of right hand sides, and would compress the verbose calculation into a boxed area where the right hand sides would appear to scroll up.

The below MWE shows a verbose calculation in the first frame, and then a `jumpy’ version of a mock scroll solution on the next. It would be very helpful if someone could make a stable, efficient and useable version.

````
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Small Example}
 Here is an example with a verbose calculation:
 \onslide<1->{Suppose $f(t)=e^{-\alpha t}$ for $\alpha>0$ then the Laplace transform is:}
 {\begin{align*}
\onslide<2->{L[f(t)]&= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\;f(t)\;dt\\}
\onslide<3->{&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\;e^{-\alpha t}\;dt\\}
\onslide<4->{&= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(\alpha +s)t}\;dt\\}
\onslide<5->{&= \int_{0}^{\infty} d \left(\frac{-e^{-(\alpha +s)t}}{\alpha+s}\right ) \\}
\onslide<6->{ &= \left .\left(\frac{-e^{-(\alpha +s)t}}{\alpha+s}\right ) \right |_{0}^{\infty}\\}
\onslide<7->{&= \left(\frac{1}{\alpha+s}\right ) }
\end{align*}}
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Small Example, Mock Scroll}

\onslide<1->{Suppose $f(t)=e^{-\alpha t}$ for $\alpha>0$ then the Laplace transform is:}
\fbox{
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{8\baselineskip}
\only<2>{\begin{align*} 
L[f(t)]&= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\;f(t)\;dt
\end{align*}}
\only<3>{\begin{align*} 
L[f(t)]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\;f(t)\;dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\;e^{-\alpha t}\;dt\\
\end{align*}}
\only<4>{\begin{align*} 
L[f(t)]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\;e^{-\alpha t}\;dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(\alpha +s)t}\;dt\\
\end{align*}}
\only<5>{
\begin{align*} 
L[f(t)]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(\alpha +s)t}\;dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} d \left(\frac{-e^{-(\alpha +s)t}}{\alpha+s}\right ) \\
\end{align*}}
\only<6>{
\begin{align*} 
L[f(t)] &=\int_{0}^{\infty} d \left(\frac{-e^{-(\alpha +s)t}}{\alpha+s}\right ) \\
&= \left .\left(\frac{-e^{-(\alpha +s)t}}{\alpha+s}\right ) \right |_{0}^{\infty}
\end{align*}}
\only<7>{
\begin{align*} 
L[f(t)] &= \left .\left(\frac{-e^{-(\alpha +s)t}}{\alpha+s}\right ) \right |_{0}^{\infty}\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{\alpha+s}\right ) 
\end{align*}}
\end{overlayarea}
}
\end{frame}


\end{document}.```
````